# Why protobuf needs to encode the type info in the message?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am reading the official [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure) doc. It states that protobuf message encodes the type of each field in the message. But, I thought the client side has the schema class file as well, so client should be able to know the types already. Why does protobuf even bother to send the type info the client already knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says right there in your linked docs:

> When the message is being decoded, the parser needs to be able to skip fields that it doesn't recognize. This way, new fields can be added to a message **without breaking old programs that do not know about them**. To this end, the "key" for each pair in a wire-format message is actually two values – the field number from your .proto file, **plus a wire type that provides just enough information to find the length** of the following value.

(emphasis mine)